# opening the phone calling app from android web for based on html code

Tags: android, android-webview, phone-number, phone-call

I'm creating an android app that is based on html and opening it in a web-view form

here's the thing i'm trying to add a phone number that when clicked opens the phone with the number inside

iv tried using the a href="tel:555-123-4567" but every time i click the link it opens the page not found in the web-view

is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

In your WebView you can [bind Javascript to Android code](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) and have full control of the Intent to fire to open any app.

Comment: i know that but i dont know the code that should be used.